# Expected a type error in WLClient.h and WLCookieExtractor.h in xcode 7.2

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst, apple-watch

I have added an Apple watch extension to my hybrid application. Bridging header has been added. But when I build the application I get the following error:

```
"Expected a type error in WLClient.h and WLCookieExtractor.h".

/Users/user/Desktop/MyProject/apps/MYAPPS/iphone/native/WorklightAPI/include/WLClient.h:163:167: error: expected a type

<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/user/Desktop/MyProject/apps/MyAPPS/iphone/native/MyApp-Header-Swift.h'
```

Has anyone faced this issue and resolved it?

Comment: What is on line `WLClient.h:163` then?

Comment: -(void) subscribeWithToken:(NSData *)deviceToken adapter:(NSString *)adapter eventSource: (NSString *)eventSource eventSourceID: (int)eventSourceID notificationType:(UIRemoteNotificationType) types delegate:(id <WLDelegate>)delegate options:(NSDictionary *)options;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIRemoteNotificationType is not supported in watchOS 2.0. watchOS 2.0 is not supported in Mobile First framework yet. Will be supported in coming versions